# Python requests unauthorized error 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, python-requests

I'm trying to make a request but I keep getting an error. Even tho I am logged in. I'm trying to program a bot that would thumbs up all my youtube video's positive comments for me. I get this however

```
401
{
  'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."',
  'Server': 'YouTubeFrontEnd',
  'Expires': 'Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST',
  'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000',
  'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Alt-Svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"',
  'Set-Cookie': 'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=wzFv76wN_9Q; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Wed, 27-Sep-2017 07:28:18 GMT; httponly, YSC=Bby4n6ZsobY; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; httponly',
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
  'Content-Length': '0',
  'Date': 'Thu, 26 Jan 2017 19:35:18 GMT',
  'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
Unauthorized
```

This is what the Chrome Network console gives me when I make the request on chrome browser.

General:

```
Request URL:https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200
```

FormData:

```
action:CAUQAhohejEydWV0eGcwb3pkaTNmbmIyMjJkcjVndW55amZmdW4zKgtvVTZVZkxHdE51STAAOABKFTExNDE1NjEzNTk0NjMwNjU3MTc2OFAA
vote_status:INDIFFERENT
session_token:QUFFLUhqbGNOaXgzaXRIN2R6ZXNVRXdvUFI2cDVzODBrd3xBQ3Jtc0ttTFdtMUViQXVzaHplM1hHYVlNVFBLSEhCMUdQTUZfX0x4cGdUa0k0TFhiekJCVFlpdlgxV2Q0NTlIQmpZakpTQ1UyUTZ4X1lFbDhTb3h3N3k4NWEyb0V6ejR2TTdRUjBIXy1KVGhqWjBzV3hLdkFvSXJIbjJZcG9xRm5YTTVQeDVzMlV1NXdoaHdKSXZDVDFkU0xHZnVPQWVyMnZPY2xTTkhuLWowUm1hR0Q3QlJ4ZGs=
```

Query string parameters:

```
action_perform_comment_action:1
```

This is the button I click on to make the request happen in chrome browser

Button HTML

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-empty yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup comment-action-buttons-renderer-thumb yt-uix-sessionlink sprite-comment-actions sprite-like i-a-v-sprite-like" type="button" onclick=";return false;" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-label="Like" data-url="/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1" data-sessionlink="itct=COoCEPBbIhMIp8vIp8fg0QIVRtB-Ch2b_QLH" data-action-type="like" data-sessionlink-target="/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1" data-action="CAUQAhojejEzM3YzaG9heXUxZnpxYWkwNGNkbHVpa2xpNXh2b2J1YmcqC29VNlVmTEd0TnVJMAA4AEoVMTE1MDUyMzM1OTE1MzQ4Nzg0MDM5UAA%3D"></button>
```

This is what I've tired

```
#starts a sesh
with requests.Session() as s:
    #Goes to login page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(post).text, "html.parser")
    #selects login form
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    #sends POST request to login
    s.post(post, form_data)

    ReuestURL3 = 'https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1'
    some33 = {'action':'CAUQAhohejEzeWpwa3pqbDJpaXRhZW0yM2VjejBodXRhcWZodnRnKgtVcnNVdVZBSmg1VTAAOABKFTEwNDcyMDg1NDE0MTM2MDE2ODY1NlAA','vote_status':'INDIFFERENT','session_token':'QUFFLUhqbVJCQXVveDdESTZfY2ROTTJWaEJLYkR4NzBUUXxBQ3Jtc0treDFSQTNVbEFhdjdpXzM3T1FaMUw1cnMxZWdUOEhVNUNYNGtfWnZqR29nMlE0NkJzejRudm51Nkx3cGgzUHZHQ0lYRF9hanhnT2JDdUlSRVVKa0hmLVRoNkE4YTJ0RXZ6Q3hSY0hJeU9nbWRqcUVwRzcyamVWN1E1Y19zaUlULU5jajRrZmEzVWs4ZmZVSEc1R3dSQXA5VDJiUDdxTkRzRFBUY3ZMX0dZZXNDbEdNRUE='}
    headers3 = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2"}
    reas = s.post(ReuestURL3, params=some33,headers=headers3,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('example@gmail.com', 'pass'))
```

but I still get a 401 error... what's going wrong why is the request failing?